# How to cite an online PDF document in LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have found an interesting article on the Internet which I want to use for my bachelor thesis. The article is an online PDF document and I am writing my thesis with LaTeX.

What type do I have to use to list that article in my bibliography? So far I have always used the @online type, but is there a special type for online PDF documents?

Comment: That strongly depends on the type of PDF document you want to cite. If it is an article in a (scholarly) journal `@article` would be more appropriate, if it is the PDF version of a book (an e-book), you would use `@book` .... `@online` is a good catch-all type if it is just a generic PDF someone put up on the web. If you can link the PDF we might be able to give more specific hints.

Comment: Here is the pdf. I would say it is kind of an article. How do you think about that? http://www.infrasoft.at/downloads/Einsatz_der_Extended_Markup_Language.pdf

Comment: The article gives information about the xml format (what is it, when do you use it, advantages, disadvantages, etc.)

Comment: It is only an `@article` in the BibTeX/`biblatex` sense of the word if it was published in a journal, nothing in the link indicates that was the case, so I would not use `@article`.  I'd use `@online` or maybe `@report`.

Comment: Ok then I'll use @online type.

Answer (score 3):

`@online` is a catch-all entry type for online resources (a bit like `@misc`), so you can never completely go wrong if you use that type for a PDF you found online. But for certain types of sources, people would expect a more specialised/sophisticated type.

- If the source you want to cite is an **article in a (scholarly) journal**, you would be expected to use **`@article`** and indicate the journal as well as date of publication, volume, page numbers etc.
- If the source you want to cite is an **(e-)book**, you may want to use the **`@book` or `@collection`** type (whichever is appropriate: `@book` is for a work written in its entirety by the same set of authors; `@collection` is for a collection of works each written by a possibly different set of authors, the overall `@collection` is usually associated with an editor).
- For **technical reports, research reports and white papers** you can use **`@report`**.
- If it is a **thesis** you would use **`@thesis`**.

You can find a list of all `biblatex` entry types in §2.1 *Entry Types* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). Each type is explained briefly and its fields are listed.

The file extension of the resource you want to cite is less important, an `@online` source may be a PDF or a HTML page or something else entirely. The important thing is the (abstract) type of the work.

---

The specific source you linked does not really fall into any of the more specialised categories mentioned above, so I would probably go with `@online`, but you could also try `@misc` or `@unpublished`. Ultimately the differences in output will not be huge, just pick the type you think makes sense the most and gives the best output.